# Trying to add 'onClick' for each image traversed by 'map()' and display a Modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here I'm using map() to traverse data and display all users with image and their name.
And I put their photo and name inside a userbox and display all userbox as flexbox. 
Then I want to add an onClick event for each photo so that when clicking the image, a modal will show up and displays each person's information. But when I try to do that, the modal cannot show up.

Please help

User.js

```
import { Modal, Button } from 'antd';
import './Users.css';

export class Users extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            visible: false, 

        };

    };

    showModal = (visible) => {
        this.setState({
            visible: true,
        });
    };

    render() {

        let { user} = this.props;
        // const { visible } = this.state;

        if(user == null){
            user = {
                name: 'null',
                gender: 'null',
                age: 'null',
                ID: 'null',
                phone: 'null',
                email: 'null',
            }
        }

        return (
            <div>
                {/* User Profile */}
                <div className="userpro">
                    {/* Title */}

                    <div className="title">
                        User Profile
                    </div>


                    {/* User List */} 
                    <div className="users">

                        {/* User Box */}
                        {user.map(user => ( 
                        <div className="userbox" key={user.code}>
                            <div className="userphoto">

                                {/* Image */}
                                <img className="photo" src={user.img} aria-hidden alt="userphoto" onClick={() => this.showModal(user)}/>
                                {/* Click to display users info */}

                                {/*<Modal visible={visible} user={this.changeSelect} />*/}
                                <Modal className="modal"
                                    title="Personal Information"
                                    footer={[
                                        <Button key="cancel" onClick={() => this.showModal(false)}>Cancel</Button>
                                    ]}
                                    centered
                                    visible={this.state.visible}
                                    onCancel={() => this.showModal(false)}>

                                    <div className="personalInfo">
                                        <p>Name: {user.name}</p>
                                        <p>Gender: {user.gender}</p>
                                        <p>Age: {user.age}</p>
                                        <p>ID: {user.ID}</p>
                                        <p>Contact Number: {user.phone}</p>
                                        <p>Email: {user.email}</p>
                                    </div>


                                </Modal>

                            </div>

                            {/* User Name */}
                            <div className="username">
                                {user.name}
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        ))}

                    </div>

                </div>  

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Users
```

Comment: `this.showModal()` instead of `this.showModal(user)` - does that make a difference?

Comment: @GBWDev no, still nothing

Comment: Have you tried binding the click handler function in your constructor? `this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);`

Comment: @j-petty Yes, I tried, but nothing changed either.

Comment: Your click handlers are being reference like this `{() => this.showModal(false)}` have you tried doing them like this `{this.showModal(false)}`?

Comment: @j-petty Yes, I tried but still nothing.